# Надо ли здесь ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

"Восприятие Гафуровым А.Г. энергетической безопасности(,) как динамической системы позволило автору сформулировать следующее определение..."

Comment: @Alenka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Запятая после " как" в значении "в качестве" не ставится.